# Get PHP or HTTP string from website, Place string in Android TextView

Tags: java, php, android, http

New to Android Programming.
Been looking for weeks now! Really Need your Help!!!
Trying to create my first Android App.

I would like to get a PHP or HTTP string from a webpage (website) and place it into a TextView in my App.

basically, I am trying to change the TextView Text into the string from the webpage.
I been having lots of problems trying to get this to work.

Can you Please put a full MainActivity.java code to help me.

Thank you Very Much guys,

I am not a programmer, but I am a Cisco CCIE Security Engineer, if you have any Networking questions I can help answer, that can be my way of returning the favor.

Thanks again.

Comment: I tried HTTPClient, I tried asynctask, I tried copying code, from resources, i found on the internet, basically i tried everything, i must be not copying the code correct in my app, because nothing is working for me, do you have a sample i can copy and past? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this tutorial, it' very helpfull

[Android, MySQL, PHP, & JSON 1 | Remote Databases Tutorial Overview](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12924/android-tutorial-using-remote-databases-php-and-mysql-part-1/)

Comment: Thank you, Going to take a look at it now.

Comment: Its a no go,,I imported the project, and all i get is errors,, hopeless for me...Thank you for helping tho

Comment: I resolved target 'android-17 ,, i downloaded api 17